# How to add customize messages for jQuery.validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**_form.html.erb**

```
    <div class="form-group grading_weighments_div">
    <%= f.fields_for :grading_weighments do |gw| %>
        <div class="grading_weighments_wrapper">
            <div class="form-group weights_div">
                <%= gw.label :weights ,class:"sr-only"%>
                    <%= gw.text_field :weights ,placeholder:"Weight", class:"form-control weights", autocomplete:"off" ,autofocus:true%>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group boxes_div">
                <%= gw.label :box_count ,class:"sr-only"%>
                    <%= gw.text_field :box_count, placeholder:"Boxes", class:"form-control boxes", autocomplete:"off" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group remove_icon_div">
                <%= gw.link_to_remove class:'btn btn-danger',  title:"Remove this weight", data: { toggle: "tooltip", placement:"bottom" }  do%>
                    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                    <%end%>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%end%>
          <%= f.link_to_add :grading_weighments ,style:'display:none', class:'btn btn-primary add_grading_weighments' , title:"Add Gradings", data: { toggle: "tooltip", placement:"right" } do%>
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                <%end%>

</div>
```

**validations**

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
 weights:{
  required:true,
  number:true,
  min:1,
},
boxes:{
  required:true,
  digits:true,
  min:1
}
```

});

Here i want to add customize messages for above fields. here i am using `jQuery.validator.addClassRules`. how's it possible .  Here i added `message:{}`. But not works.

Comment: Have you tried to read documentation? http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are doing the right thing in the wrong place.

If you have a look at [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/custom-messages-data-demo.html) you will see that you can set custom messages by adding some information to the HTML element to be validated.

They show for example:

```
<input id="cemail" 
    data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address" 
    data-msg-required="Please enter your email address" 
    data-rule-email="true" 
    data-rule-required="true" 
    name="email" 
    aria-required="true">
```

All the rules are referred to the form element name and not the id.

Comment: I am not validate with Id in form. I am using jquery validate add rules for validations

Comment: This is what the plugin author describes as the method to use his plugin. Have a closer look at the documentation (link is provided by two of us...) and you can see if what you want to do is feasible with that plugin

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/  Please find this link to difference validate with form id and rules of jquery

Comment: The rules are one thing, the mesages another. The rules are set to say how long, what format and so on for the field. Messages doesn't go here! Rules are just overwriting existing one (and they will inherit the same text unless you change them on a field base) or creating new one (and you will have to specify messages with the shown technique).

Comment: I didn't get you nice one

Comment: You can define a custom rule to say that a name must be at least 10 chars (while the standard is 3 chars - [not real data]). This means that the plugin will trigger the rule when it comes to less than 10 chars and not less than 3 only. (Carl won't pass the custom rule but ok for the standard one). To define a custome message for that you have to do it on a input field basis as I shown you and you cannot do on a rule base.